WordPress - swiper carousel cause unwanted horizontal scroll
I have an elementor website where I will need to insert some different carousels of images inside the post content. Initially I was using elementor and I've made a template for each carousle I will need. At the moment I've decided to switch to a shortcode that will use the included swiper of elementor and create a carousel. This is the code
function custom_carousel_shortcode($atts) {
    
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'ids' => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        'custom-carousel'
    );

    $image_ids = explode(',', $atts['ids']);

    $carousel_html = '';

    foreach ($image_ids as $image_id) {
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($image_id, 'full');
        if ($image_url) {
            $carousel_html .= '<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="' . esc_url($image_url) . '" class="swiper-slide-img" /></div>';
        }
    }

    $output = '<div class="elementor-widget-container"><div class="elementor-element elementor-widget elementor-image-carousel"><div id="swiper_init" class="swiper-container"><div class="swiper-wrapper">' . $carousel_html . '</div><div class="swiper-pagination"></div><div class="swiper-button-prev"></div><div class="swiper-button-next"></div></div></div></div>';

    $output .= '<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(window).on("load", function() {
            console.log(elementorFrontend.utils);
            let mySwiper;
            const swiperElement = $(".swiper-container");
            const swiperConfig = {
                //centeredSlides: true,
                loop: false,
                pagination: {
                    el: ".swiper-pagination"
                },
                navigation: {
                    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
                },
                //autoplay: {
                //  delay: 5000
                //},
                //slidesPerView: 1,
                //slidesPerGroup: 1,
            };
            //
            if (typeof elementorFrontend.utils.swiper === "function") {
                new elementorFrontend.utils.swiper(swiperElement, swiperConfig).then((newSwiperInstance) => {
                    
                    console.log("New Swiper instance is ready: ", newSwiperInstance);
                    mySwiper = newSwiperInstance;
                });
            } else if (typeof Swiper === "function") {
                console.log("Swiper global variable is ready, create a new instance: ", Swiper);
                mySwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", swiperConfig);
            } else {
                console.error("Swiper initialization failed.");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('custom-carousel', 'custom_carousel_shortcode');

At the moment swiper will be loaded correctly where I'm testing it and is able to get the images using their id. My main problem at the moment is with the layout. I've noticed that I'm unable to have only a single slide displayed and other slides that are part of the carousel will be positioned on the left or right side of the screen, this will cause an horizontal scroll. How I can fix this and get a carousel that will work like the carousel widget of elementor? Do i need to adjust swiper settings or to use CSS?
UPDATE
I've fixed the CSS problem using the suggested rule posted into the comments. At the moment I've noticed that when I put the shortcode multiple time inside a page, Only the first carousel will work, the other that will be rendered will not work, by looking at the console I've noticed that the swiper instance will target only the firts carousel inserted into the page and not every carousel. How I can fix this little other problem?

Setting the slidesPerView option and adding .swiperContainer{ overflow-x: hidden; } may answer your need but would be easier to reprensent the problem without a minimal reproductible example to show what you have.

I've tried with the slidesPerView setting but the problem still remain. need to test using the suggested CSS rule

Thank you for the suggestion. Seems working perfectly. I will do a test on the production website. If you want, leave a reply so I can vote it and mark as answered the question

You can set how many slides are displayed at the same time with the slidesPerView option.
Also, to avoid having an horizontal scrollbar, you can use overflow-x: hidden; and set it to your container (in your case, .swiper-container).
